# React - update object within object within array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

Having trouble updating a field whose value if within an object within an object within an array:

```
      [
        { animals: { an1: 'lynx', an2: 'tiger' }, location: 'asia' },
        { animals: { an1: 'pigeon', an2: 'eagle' }, location: 'europe' },
      ];
```

```
const handleChange = (e, input) => {
    let updatedList = data.map((item, i) => {
        if (i === index) {
          const allAnimals = { ...item.animals };
          allAnimals[input] = e.target.value;

          return { ...item, animals: allAnimals }; 
        }
        return item;
      });
    
    setData(updatedList);

  }
```

How would I update `an1` or `an2` in the `animals` object?

Comment: You need to show what `e.target.value` and `input` contains. And what is `data`?

Comment: `e.target.value` = 'test',  `input` = 'an1'.  `data` is the array above the function

Answer (score 0):

If you simply would like to replace all indexes the following should work:

```js
const data = [
  { animals: { an1: 'lynx', an2: 'tiger' }, location: 'asia' },
  { animals: { an1: 'pigeon', an2: 'eagle' }, location: 'europe' },
];

const handleChange = (e, input) =>
   data.map(it => ({
    ...it,
    animals: {
      ...it.animals,
      [input]: e.target.value,
    }
  }))

console.log(handleChange({
  target: {
    value: 'test',
  }},
  'an2'
))
```

Notice, that this will replace/add the new value to each array.